# Is there a way to restore a save file?

Tags: android, bloons-td-5, google-play-games

I was attempting to complete the new game type added, and I lost. So, to make sure I did not have to re-do the first 4 levels, I went to go force-stop the game (which resets to last save, so before I lost), but my finger slipped, and I un-installed the game. After re-installing it, I realized I had lost all 70 of my levels and all of my upgrades. Is there a way to get my save back?

I am playing on Android through Google Play, so I was expecting it to save my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you saved your data to the cloud, there is no way of restoring your levels. There is only a "restore purchases".

The only other thing you could do is login to a saved NinjaKiwi profile or Kongregate profile that would load as your main profile if you had been using it previously.

Comment: So Google Play does not work as a cloud?

Comment: The game itself must use your Google Play account to save your game - developer choice. Since Bloons has it's own servers with NinjaKiwi, it doesn't use Google Play in that way.

Comment: Seems like I am out of luck, thanks though.

Comment: @ShadowZ. That really sucks...I play a couple maps of Bloons every now and then and I'm pretty high. If my save game got erased I'd quit forever.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem. I wanted to restore Bloon TD5.

After I emailed NinjaKiwi for support, they told me to use "the Helium Application" (from Google Play).

It really works.

Answer (score 0):

*Helium* definitely works very well. The only down side is that you have to pay $5. It may seem that you don't have to pay the $5 when you first back-up your Bloons TD 5 save file, but you must have the premium app to use the recover function.

If you do choose to use this $5 app, which in my many hours of experience with Bloons is worth it, you must download it on both of your phones and your computer. The computer version is free, but as mentioned, you will need to purchase the premium version on your phone.

1. Open all of the *Helium* applications on your two phones and your
   computer.
2. Sync both of your phones to your email account.
3. Then, back up your Bloons file to your computer from the phone that the save is currently on.
4. Next, use the phone that you want the save on and access your old phone through the *Helium* app.
5. Download the save file on your new phone (from your old phone) and you  should be good to go.